# Add an event on ng-show

Tags: angularjs

i'm not an angular master and i try to do something.
Suppose a fonctionality like "i like / i dislike".
When you're on an article, you can click on the "i like" button. If you already liked the article, this button is hidden and the "i don't like anymore" appears.

```
    <button ng-hide="like" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right" ng-click="iLike()">I like</button>
<button ng-show="like" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" ng-click="notLike()">Don't like anymore</button>
```

Everything work as expected when i reload the page but not on click action.
Basically my iLike function looks like and i think miss behavior comes from a missing return or an event to fire :(

```
$scope.iLike = function(){
        ##hereIDoAnAPICalls##, function(){ 
           $scope.like = false;
        }, function(){
            $scope.like = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is $scope.meToo the right name?

Comment: i did the correction into the question, thanks for asking

Comment: I don't understand what this code is supposed to do... why are you writing two functions after each other when you are referencing only one scope variable?

Comment: @doodeec because i call api.xx.com/ilike and api.xx.com/idislike and the response has an impact on other scope variables

Comment: I got it now... I ignored the comments at first sight... so it looks like you have to call $apply, since the API call is probably async and the click event is invoked outside of angular

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap scope variable assignment into apply, I think it could help since API call is probably asynchronous and click event is invoked from outside of angular

```
$scope.iLike = function() {
    APIcall.then(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.like = false;
        });
    }, function () {...the same...});
};
```